# Locale in JHipseter

Tags: jhipster

There are two languages, English and Spanish, in our JHipster application with Vue for the front end. I retrieve the locale in a controller with

```
Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
```

Regardless of the language selection in the front end, the value is always the same. I don't see any transfer between the front end and backend when I change the locale, nor a locale data in either the header or the request URL of a Rest request. I guess that the locale is disconnected between the front end and backend in JHipster. If that is true, any suggestion on how I can modify the code to let the backend reflect the locale on the front end?

Comment: For me, the simplest would to send a request to a RestController each time the locale changes and then persist it in db. It could also depend on the auth type you use, some identity providers share the locale in the auth token

Comment: The front end likely holds the state of locale. If I could extract the data, I could put it in a request as a query string to meet a need in the controller. This approach would demand less work than placing the locale information (for each user account, I assume) in DB.

Comment: You can do this in `translation.service.ts`, add a call to whatever REST endpoint you want inside the `refreshTranslation()` method. I don't fully understand what you want to achieve (or why).

Comment: @vicpermir Thank you very much for your advice. A few places have this.$store.getters.currentLanguage. Is the $store accessible in a service.ts? To answer your question, some REST APIs need the locale to function, for example, to save an entity data with the locale as its attribute. And also to retrieve data only for one specified country through an API.