# How The Form Validation Is Done In JHIpster Front End?

Tags: vue.js, jhipster, vuelidate

I need to modify a form validation because some of the inputs are generated by the system instead of human input, those input fields will be filled in a controller. In other words, its DTO has fewer fields with validation constraints than the entity class. I am investigating

```
$v.myEntity.$invalid
```

I have a look at all related typescript files and don't see how it is done. Vue is the framework for the front end. I assume that it is the same for the front end regardless of the Javascript framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JHipster + Vue uses [vuelidate](https://vuelidate.js.org/) for form validation. Look for an object called `validations` near the top of your `.component.ts` files.

Something like this:

```js
const validations: any = {
  testEntity: {
    testField: {
      required,
    },
  },
};
```

For example, to make `testField` no longer required on the front end, remove `required,` on that `.component.ts` and the `required` keyword on the corresponding input on your `.vue` file.

Remember to also remove the `@NotNull` on the entity DTO so it's not rejected, and then you can fill it up with whatever you need on the server side.

Comment: Thanks very much. I find the validation in xxx-update.component.ts. After removing those validation fields, the form submission works as desired. I already removed the validation constraints in the DTO. Also, any advice on locale usage (here is my locale question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68642907/locale-in-jhipseter)? How to get the language setting in the jhi-navbar..component.ts for a REST call to the back end Java code so that the right locale data can be used for the backend?